# Stored Procedure variable from table

Tags: sql

I would like to set my variable '@Xdate' to the field 'updated' from 'dbo.Mtabel'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Mproc]
(
@snumber nvarchar(50),
@inumber nvarchar(10),
@tdate datetime
)
AS
IF exists (Select snumber, updated FROM dbo.Mtabel Where snumber = @snumber AND inumber = @inumber)
GO
declare  
    @Xdate datetime,
    @sdate datetime

select
    @Xdate = dbo.@updated,
    @Ydate = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used, so you get the right attention! (Non ANSI SQL involved here...)

Comment: Side note if this is for **SQL Server**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @xdate = updated, @ydate=getdate() FROM dbo.Mtabel WHERE snumber = @snumber AND inumber = @inumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Mproc]
(
    @snumber nvarchar(50),
    @inumber nvarchar(10),
    @tdate datetime
)
AS

declare @Xdate datetime, @Ydate datetime
Select @Xdate = updated, @Ydate = getDate() FROM dbo.Mtabel Where snumber = @snumber AND inumber = @inumber
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  -- @Xdate contains 'updated', @Ydate contains current datetime
  ...
END
GO
```

This is to prevent you making several calls for the same data.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable
    ( id varchar(50),Date1 Date, Date2 Date)
;

INSERT INTO #YourTable
    (id, Date1, Date2)
VALUES
    ('1','2015-01-10','2015-01-20'),
    ('2','2015-01-20','2015-01-11'),
    ('3','2015-01-15','2014-01-15'),
    ('4','2015-02-18','2016-03-09')
;
--   select * from #YourTable


Declare @Xdate date
select @Xdate= Date2 from #YourTable where Date2 > GETDATE()
print @Xdate
```